# Can anyone know how to fix this code in C?

Tags: c

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  long fac(int n);
  int judge(long n);

  int main(void)
  {
  int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, exact;
  a = b = c = d = e = f = g = 0;


  for (exact = 1; exact <= (99999); exact++)
  {
   if (judge(exact) == 1)
         if (fac(exact) == exact)
              printf("%d\n", exact);  

   if (judge(exact) == 2)
    {
      a = exact / 10;
      b = exact - a*10;
       if(fac(a)+fac(b) == exact)
           printf("%d\n", exact);
        }
   if (judge(exact) == 3)
        {
        a = exact /100;
        b = exact/10 - a*10;
        c = exact - a*100 - b*10;
        if(fac(a) + fac(b) + fac(c) == exact)
            printf("%d\n", exact);
        }
    if (judge(exact) == 4)
        {
        a = exact/1000;
        b = exact/100 - a*10;
        c = exact/10 - a*100 - b*10;
        d = exact - a*1000 - b*100 - c*10;
        if (fac(a) + fac(b) + fac(c) + fac(d) == exact)
            printf("%d\n", exact);
        }
    if (judge(exact) == 5)
        {
        a = exact/10000;
        b = exact/1000 - (a*10);
        c = exact/100 - (a*100) - (b*10);
        d = exact/10 - (a*1000) - (b*100) - (c*10);
        e = exact - (a * 10000) - (b * 1000) - (c * 100) - (d*10);
        if (fac(a) + fac(b) + fac(c) + fac(d) + fac(e) == exact)
             printf("%d\n", exact);
        }

}

return 0;
}








 long fac(int times)
{
   long sum = 1;
int i, j;    
for (i = 1; i <= times; i++)
{   
    j = i;
    sum = sum * j;
}
return sum;
}

int judge(long n)
{

int length = 1;

while (n > 1)
{
    length++;
    n = n/10;
}
return length;
}
```

This program tends to calculate all specific numbers like this abc = a!b!c! (a! is the factorial)
I already knew there are only 4 numbers who satisfy this condition, they are 1, 2, 145, and 40585.
But I run my program, which just show 1 and 145. 
What should I to fix this? or you can give me a smarter way to do this?

(I built two function, fac() to calculate factorial, judge() to show how many numbers it contains.)

Thanks very much !

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger. With a debugger you can step through the code line by line, while monitoring variable values and changes to them.

Comment: Please specify your problem in a better way, ie what are `a`, `b` and `c` single digits? No, so tell us what are their values in 40585. And it is probably not a!b!c!, but a!+b!+c!, isn't it for 145?

Comment: Your `judge` function is wrong, as it returns length=2 for n=2 (for example).

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès sorry to confuse you, 40585 = 4! + 0! + 5! + 8! + 5!

Comment: Then edit your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your judge function return wrong value.you can correct it using 2 ways. 1st approach

```
 int judge(long n)
 {
    int length = 0;
    while (n > 0)
    {
            length++;
            n = n/10;
    }
    return length;
 }
```

Another approach is you take extra variables int size and char str[10].

```
 size = sprintf(str,"%d",exact);     // find length of digit
 if (size == 1){              // check lenght of digit == 1
```

both approaches return correct results.

Answer (score 0):

Change your "judge" function(which is actually calculating number of digits) as follows

```
int judge(long n) {
    int length = 0;
    while (n!=0) {
       n = n/10;
       length++;
    } 
  return length;
}
```

I'm sure it will work

Answer (score 0):

Your `judge` function is returning an incorrect value. In this function, you detect the no of digits of the number. It should return `1` for input `1` and `5` for input `40585`. It is returning `6` for the second input.

It should be changed as follows.

```
int judge(long n)
{

  int length = 0;

  while (n >= 1)
  {
    length++;
    n = n/10;
  }
  return length;
}
```